# Post Migration Snippet with Knex

Tags: knex.js

Is there a way with Knex, or knex-hooks to execute a code snippet or final database tasks?  Specifically, I want to recreate some views after any/all table changes are complete?  I guess I could put them in a future dated file, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You mean after the migrations are done?

Comment: Yes, ideally when you add a migration the code would still be executed at the end